# how to set shadow border with round corners in android (using open source only)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout

I want to create a container like this:

[image]

I have tried this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:weightSum="1">



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:src="@android:drawable/alert_dark_frame"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#152"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dip"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:background="#120"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.07" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:text="--"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.88" />



</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my output:

[image]

how can I create the shadow border and rounded corners?

I want the corners to be around the whole container and not on each shape\color separately.

So I need to user "upper" and "lower" corners?

Comment: its extremely simple: create a custom container (in this case `LinearLayout`) and override its drawing code - at most 10-15 lines of effective code

Comment: yeah, its 10 lines of code that do the trick: i was too pessimistic, just override `dispatchDraw` and do the custom drawing stuff

Comment: Yeah, if only Android had some widget to provide rounded shaded cards, something like [`CardView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html).. :D

Comment: @Lamorak try to use `Cardview` to clip the child views, its not that easy...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a library for creating nice layouts with shadow.
Try this one [here](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/shadow-layout).

Comment: I can use only open-source projects

Comment: @EladBenda and `dmytrodanylyk/shadow-layout` is a close-source project?

Comment: @GjokoBozinov apparently Elad Benda was unable to find the java files in the link you posted